# Trying to publish to joint with python script

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String


import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float64

def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/rx150/wrist_rotate_controller/command', Float64, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('rx150_talker', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        position = -1.0
        rospy.loginfo(position)
        pub.publish(position)
        rate.sleep()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

When executing this script the gazebo simulated robot doesn't respond to the joint command I give.

The simulated robot however does respond to this command when I type it in the terminal:

`rostopic pub -1 /rx150/wrist_angle_controller/command std_msgs/Float64 "data: -1.0"`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404973/trying-to-publish-to-joint-with-python-script/) by [PGTKing](https://answers.ros.org/users/60529/pgtking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your ROS node talker uses different topic than your terminal command, in node you have `/rx150/wrist_rotate_controller/command` and in the `rostopic` you have `/rx150/wrist_angle_controller/command`.

You can check if you are publishing everything correctly with `rostopic echo`.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PGTKing](https://answers.ros.org/users/60529/pgtking/) on 2022-08-12**:
Thank you, sometimes you overlook small mistakes. Appreciate it.